# Set programmatically margin values on a custom view in a FrameLayout

Tags: android

I define a view. This view contains a picture and the user can interact with. I define a FrameLayout in my main layout and i add this view programmatically in this FrameLayout.

In the View constructor, i define a MarginLayutParams to put this view on the center of te screen. The code is :

```
mLayoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight);
mLayoutParams.setMargins(toCenterX, toCenterY, 0, 0);
setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
```

The margin values don't works... The view is correctly resize to width and height defines but the view isn't scale to the center of the view by the margin values...

Edit :

Schemas of my views :

```
                         -> View1 (i want sclae this view to the center)
Activity -> FrameLayout  -> View2 (i want scale this view under the view 1)
                         -> View3 (i want scale this view at the top right)
```

Here a sample of my ViewGroup. I implement a ViewGroup to manage all views :

```
public class MainView extends ViewGroup {

public BackgroundView mBackgroundWheelArea;
public BackgroundView mBackgroundLabelArea;
public WheelCoreView wheelCoreArea;
public LabelView labelArea;

public WheelOfFortuneActivity mActivity;

public MainView(Context pContext) {
    super(pContext);
    mActivity = (WheelOfFortuneActivity) pContext;
    mBackgroundWheelArea = new BackgroundView(pContext, R.drawable.menu_background);
    wheelCoreArea = new WheelCoreView(pContext, mActivity.fromPixelToDp(mBackgroundWheelArea
            .getBackgroundHeight()), mActivity.fromPixelToDp(mBackgroundWheelArea
            .getBackgroundWidth()));
    labelArea = new LabelView(pContext, "Web");
    mBackgroundLabelArea = new BackgroundView(pContext, R.drawable.menu_background_label);
    this.addView(wheelCoreArea, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean pChanged, int pL, int pT, int pR, int pB) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.layout(100, 100, 0, 0);
    }

}

@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
    child.draw(canvas);
    return true;
}

}
```

But the wheelCoreArea view no move from the top left corner ! :(

Can you help me ?

Regards.

Comment: do child.layout(100, 100, 100+child.getWidth(), 100+child.getHeight());

Comment: @user7777777777 Nothing happen, my view stays at the top left...

Comment: i have modified my answer. should work.

Comment: I use in onDraw() in my custom View or in the ViewGroup ?

Comment: @user7777777777 It's perhaps because i use a FrameLayout to define the main view ? If i use a RelativeLayout, it can be work.

Comment: dont override ondraw then. i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `onLayout()` method and set the view bounds manually instead of setting the margins.

Call  `view.layout(top, left, right, bottom);` Maintain the bounds in member variables.

If the size of this view also changes you may need to override the `onMeasure` method too.

### Edit

Try this formula to calculate the view placement points.

```
viewLeft = displayWidth()/2 - viewWidth/2;
viewTop = displayHeight()/2 - viewHeight/2;
```

Call  `view.layout(viewLeft , viewTop , viewLeft + viewWidth, viewTop + viewHeight);`

Comment: did u have to override the onMeasure  method?

Comment: One question :
I override onLayout() on my FrameLayout then I iterate on all children and call view.layout(top, left, right, bottom); for each ?

Comment: I'm testing, i don't override onMeasure for the moment.

Comment: So, i don't have the method onLayout in my activity. If i override this in my view, i don't have children (see my edit in the first post). I must add a View who contains all views ?

Comment: can u add a snapshot to the post.. how do calculate centerX and centerY

Comment: I get the metrics of the phone and i take the height/2 and width/2
I'll see to add a snapshot

Comment: But you'll place the view left top at the center point, so it will not appear centered.

Comment: I can't post picture... 
So, the center is not a problem. I implemnt a new class extends ViewGroup. This class contains all views (a view contains a bitmap). I override onLayout (in the class extends ViewGroup) and iterate on children. I call view.layout(100,100,0,0); 
My bitmaps must be move from the top left of the screen but he doesn't... :(